# PL/SQL datetime update set results in time 00:00:00

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to set a datetime one second less than the end_ts datetime with sql as below

```
UPDATE Table1 SET 
          UPDTD_DT=(SELECT TO_DATE(END_TS-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          FROM View1) WHERE id = '123';
```

But after ran this update, the datetime is 00:00:00. I displayed and checked the TO_DATE(END_TS-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') which looks fine.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(END_TS-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM View1 is 25/03/2022 10:14:44
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will View1 never have more than one row?

Comment: What is the datatype of column END_TS ?

Comment: View1 only have one row for the exact date returnning
And the datatype of column End_TS is DATE.
And the return of 'SELECT TO_DATE(END_TS-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM View1' is 25/03/2022 10:14:44 which is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`). At best, it will do nothing and, at worst, it will raise an exception or, as you are finding, give an unexpected output.

You want:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET   UPDTD_DT = (SELECT END_TS - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM View1)
WHERE id       = '123';
```

*Or `1/(24*60*60)` instead of `INTERVAL '1' SECOND`, but the latter is probably easier to comprehend what you mean during a code review.*

---

If you use:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(END_TS-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   View1
```

and `END_TS` is a `DATE` column then `TO_DATE` expects a string as its first argument so your `DATE` value will be implicitly cast to a string using the default format model for date-to-string conversions (the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter) before being converted back to a `DATE` and the query is effectively:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           END_TS-1/(24*60*60),
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   View1
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match the `'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'` format model then you will get an exception. If it does match but does not display the time component (i.e. the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD/MM/YYYY`) then the default time component of midnight will be used.

Theoretically, you could solve the problem by changing the user's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

But then you would need to set it for every user who runs the query and users can change their own session parameters at any time so you would have to ensure it is set each time you run the query. So this is not considered good practice.

It is considered better practice to not use `TO_DATE` to a `DATE` value and avoid the implicit cast to a string.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5DXKmDvL)

Comment: @Rich Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76454554/edit) to include a [MRE] that demonstrates the problem. You can see from the Fiddle linked in my answer that using `TO_DATE` and an incorrect `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` recreates the problem and removing the `TO_DATE` solves the problem; if you say that that does not work for you then you need to provide us with a way to recreate the problem; if you cannot then we will not be able to understand what is causing the issue and cannot help you to solve it.

Comment: After restarted the SQL Developer and tried again. It works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers to my question. Both are correct and hit the point. But I can only accept one solution. I am grateful to both Koen Lostrie and MTO.

Answer (score 4):

Reason that is happening is that you're doing a `TO_DATE` on a column of type `DATE`. There is no need to do that.

Check the following example (the wrapping TO_CHAR is only for display purposes):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(sysdate-1/(24*60*60),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as unneeded_todate,
       TO_CHAR(
         sysdate-1/(24*60*60),
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as correct_code         
  FROM dual;

UNNEEDED_TODATE            CORRECT_CODE              
-------------------------- --------------------------
12-JUN-2023 00:00          12-JUN-2023 08:06
```

So, to fix your issue:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET 
          UPDTD_DT=(SELECT END_TS-1/(24*60*60)
          FROM View1) WHERE id = '123';
```

Or... use `INTERVAL` to add/substract.

```
UPDATE Table1 
   SET 
        UPDTD_DT= (SELECT END_TS - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
                     FROM View1) 
WHERE id = '123';
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault. I restarted the SQL Developer and tried again. It works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers to my question. Both are correct and hit the point. But I can only accept one solution. I am grateful to both Koen Lostrie and MTO.